# Is there an established algorithm to produce a hash number from a person’s DNA?

Tags: human-genetics

It is often said that a person’s DNA uniquely identifies that person. Is there an established algorithm that can/could take values of a specific DNA sample to produce a digit string unique to its source, perhaps as a hash of the quantification of DNA components?

I am a software engineer with very little knowledge of genetics, so I’ll stipulate this may be a dumb question for those skilled in the art.

However, as hash spaces are easily defined that can uniquely represent trillions of elements, it seems me that this should be possible and likely has been worked out.

Comment: This rather assumes 100% copy fidelity in every cell of the body as a basis, that's [not quite the case](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6311130/).

Comment: One slight correction. Not all humans have different DNA sequences — identical twins start out the same in this respect.

Comment: As a link to a paper is not an answer, and I cam not competent to summarize the paper, I just provide this info in a comment. Have you seen Zobrist's ["Ordered Minimal Perfect Hash of the Human Genome and Implications for Duplicate Finding"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5170970)? It requires membership of IEEE or institutional access.

Answer (score 3):

There are various approaches based on sequence k-mers that do more or less this. I don't off the top of my head know which ones are the most trusted for minimizing collisions, which appears to be your motivation. For a general purpose k-mer library you might look at [khmer](https://github.com/dib-lab/khmer). For something a little less biology focused you might look at [murmurhash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash), which I believe is nonetheless used extensively in bio applications.

[MinHash](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-016-0997-x) has been used fairly extensively to generate sequence hashes efficiently in large nucleotide sequence collections. However, it relies upon a summary that may not guarantee uniqueness at the level you are interested in.

For a thread discussing different approaches and with more background, see [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/184993/).

If you are interested in human sequences specifically, there is a good amount of material out there on constructing unique hashes, though I'm not personally so familiar with it. [Here is one reference at google-random](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.5517.pdf), [here is another](https://almob.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13015-016-0069-5).

It's also true as stated in the comments that the sequence of an individual is noisy. I would argue that there is a strong enough central tendency in the distribution of sequences for a human that it's still a worthwhile exercise, but understanding this shortcoming will be crucial for interpreting data (especially given the error-prone nature of sequence reconstruction via sequencing and assembly).